# I'm having issues displaying text on a point in a graph when you hover over it in Processing4

Tags: java, processing

I'm having issues displaying text on a point in a graph when you hover over it in Processing4.

I have tried using a loop to display the text but it seems the graph plot doesn't allow anything display on it.

I dont know what else to do.
I have tried using the GTooltip function in the G4P library (with no success).

Here's my attempt so far:

```
import interfascia.*;

import controlP5.*;

import grafica.*;

import g4p_controls.*;

GPlot plot1;
GButton clearButton;
GButton updateButton;
GPointsArray dataPoints;
GToolTip tooltip;

void setup() {
  size(2000, 1300);
  createGUI();
  createPlot();
}

void createGUI() {}

void createPlot() {
  plot1 = new GPlot(this);
  plot1.setPos(0, 0);
  plot1.setDim(1500, 1000);
  plot1.getTitle().setText("MAP A");
  plot1.getXAxis().getAxisLabel().setText("Vehicle Weight (lbs)");
  plot1.getYAxis().getAxisLabel().setText("Acceleration time 0 to 60 (Sec)");
  plot1.setPointColor(color(0, 0, 0, 255));
  plot1.setPointSize(10);

  // Sample data points
  dataPoints = new GPointsArray();
  dataPoints.add(1500, 5.0);  // Sample data point 1
  dataPoints.add(2000, 6.5);  // Sample data point 2
  dataPoints.add(2500, 4.2);  // Sample data point 3
  dataPoints.add(1800, 5.8);  // Sample data point 4

  
}

void draw() {
  plot1.beginDraw();
  plot1.drawBackground();
  plot1.drawBox();
  plot1.drawXAxis();
  plot1.drawYAxis();
  plot1.drawTitle();
  plot1.drawGridLines(GPlot.BOTH);
  plot1.drawPoints(); 
  plot1.endDraw();
}
```

Comment: Error message states GToolTip class does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You're close, but you still need 3 more "ingredients":

1. your points should have labels (e.g. `dataPoints.add(1500, 5.0, "Sample data point 1");`)
2. you should assign those points to the plot via `setPoints()`: `plot1.setPoints(dataPoints);`
3. you need to manually force drawing the labels in `draw()` (otherwise the labels will be rendered [*if* the mouse is pressed or dragged *and* `activatePointLabels()` was called](https://github.com/jagracar/grafica/blob/master/src/grafica/GPlot.java#L2942C9-L2942C9)): `plot1.drawLabelsAt(mouseX, mouseY);` (within the plot's `beginDraw()`/`endDraw()` context calls)

(You should also remove any code you don't use)

```java
import grafica.*;

GPlot plot1;
GPointsArray dataPoints;

void setup() {
  size(1920, 1080);
  createPlot();
  
}

void createPlot() {
  
  plot1 = new GPlot(this);
  plot1.setPos(0, 0);
  plot1.setDim(1280, 720);
  plot1.getTitle().setText("MAP A");
  plot1.getXAxis().getAxisLabel().setText("Vehicle Weight (lbs)");
  plot1.getYAxis().getAxisLabel().setText("Acceleration time 0 to 60 (Sec)");
  plot1.setPointColor(color(0, 0, 0, 255));
  plot1.setPointSize(30);
  
  // Sample data points
  dataPoints = new GPointsArray();
  dataPoints.add(1500/2, 5.0, "sample data point 1");
  dataPoints.add(2000/2, 6.5, "sample data point 2");
  dataPoints.add(2500/2, 4.2, "sample data point 3");
  dataPoints.add(1800/2, 5.8, "sample data point 4");
  // populate plot with points
  plot1.setPoints(dataPoints);
}

void draw() {
  plot1.beginDraw();
  plot1.drawBackground();
  plot1.drawBox();
  plot1.drawXAxis();
  plot1.drawYAxis();
  plot1.drawTitle();
  plot1.drawGridLines(GPlot.BOTH);
  plot1.drawPoints(); 
  // force drawing labels on hover
  plot1.drawLabelsAt(mouseX, mouseY);
  plot1.endDraw();
}
```

(I tweaked the sketch dimensions and plot point coordinates to fit on my laptop screen: feel free to adjust as needed of course)

This is the first time I use this library and noticed the [library website](https://jagracar.com/grafica.php) isn't hosting the documentation. Processing libraries tend to come with javadocs generated documentation. You should be able to find that in **Documents/Processing/libraries/grafica/reference**.